# Disable resolving for CSS/SASS/SCSS/LESS URLs in Webpack 5

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, sass

In SASS, I have a CSS rule with a URL that looks like:

```
.eSearchFAQsAccord-q {
  &::after {
    content: url("./images/caret.svg");
  }
}
```

By default, Webpack will resolve this (though it chokes on my SVG). I want it to NOT resolve. I want the browser to load this image separately, from my `static` directory.

I'm not sure what to say about what I've tried so far. I've tried a *lot* of settings from around the web in my Webpack config that didn't work...

Here's my Webpack config, which I think is pretty out-of-the-box:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",
  entry: {
    index: `./src/index.js`,
  },
  target: "web",
  output: {
    path: `${__dirname}/dist`,
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin({
      patterns: [{ from: "static" }],
    }),
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    inline: true,
    host: "localhost",
    port: 8080,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true,
    },
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
        use: [
          "style-loader",
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: "sass-loader",
            options: {
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        enforce: "pre",
        use: ["source-map-loader"],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

I'm sure my issue is because I don't have intimate knowledge of Webpack, but the documentation I don't think is particularly intuitive at a glance.

Comment: Are you using css-loader and if so try removing it. https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/

Comment: Yes, I  think my config is close to default setup... Is that to say this is the way one would go about disabling the feature? Foregoing css-loader altogether?

Comment: Why would you use webpack for CSS at all? The only time you need that is if you're using styled components (e.g. JS code that imports a css file, which is... questionable, in a lot of cases). For normal page CSS, you don't need webpack in the slightest, just compile your sass to css in your asset dir, and load it normally with a `<link>` element in your HTML template.

Comment: So "ah-ha" moment that I could turn off css-loader and implement the `content` in `.css` files, but that seems like a workaround to me... For future, I should ask if there is a setting that will accommodate doing this in my SASS/SCSS. Is that possible?

Comment: ...For organization if nothing else. Should I really need to create a separate file for a single CSS rule to live separately from related styling? I can accept that probably, but would like to know if that's the only way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think Webpack 5 `css-loader` resolves this `url()` calls by default, and you need to disable it manually:

```js
        loader: "css-loader",
        options: {
          // Add this option
          url: false,
        },
```

[More in the docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url)

Maybe there are same options for your other loaders, but I'm pretty sure you just need to disable it for `css-loader` only

Comment: Of course it was simple. I naively tried setting the param in both `sass-loader` and `css-loader`, and got an error from that. But once I did *only* what you said, it worked. I think a takeaway is that it seems those should not be expected to have similar options and configuration, but rather features from one would be redundant in the other, since they are intended to be used in tandem. Cool... Thanks!