# How do I configure webpack to ignore my non-existing resource in scss?

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, sass

I receive an error when compiling my scss file.

In the .scss file I have:

```scss
    body {
      background-image: url("/static/background.webp");
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
    error  in ./src/scss/general.scss?vue&type=style&index=0&prod&lang=scss&external
    Syntax Error: HookWebpackError: Cannot find module './static/background.webp'
```

I have a webserver that will generate this `background.webp` but it doesn't exist in this project.
My solution is to either put a temporary file in my project so it can be resolved or a cleaner approach would be to configure the project to ignore this file.

I need help with how to make the scss loader ignore this file.

I am using webpack 5, node 16/npm 8, vue 2 and building with vue-cli-service 5.

Comment: Never dealt with this specific problem before, but I think you want to [pass a filter function to the css-loader options](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#url). Then you'd have sass-loader after that in your config. [Related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68403193/disable-resolving-for-css-sass-scss-less-urls-in-webpack-5).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are receiving is due to the Webpack configuration from Vue CLI whereby it includes [`css-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/). It describes itself as:

> The `css-loader` interprets `@import` and `url()` like `import`/`require()` and will resolve them.

Thus you should consider altering the `css-loader` configuration of your project, by [using the `css.loaderOptions` option](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-loaderoptions) in `vue.config.js`.

For example, to completely disable `css-loader`'s resolution of any `url()` or `image-set()` functions, [set `url` to `false`](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#boolean):

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        url: false
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Or, for only the `/static/background.webp` value, [pass an object with the `filter` property as a function](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/css-loader/#object) that passes `false` for the given value:

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  css: {
    loaderOptions: {
      css: {
        url: {
          filter(url) {
            return url !== '/static/background.webp';
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```